# Results are returning as Undefined

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simple page that contains 2 iframes. Text is input into iframeA and once a button is clicked on iframeB I want it to display the text from iframeA but it just displays undefined. I feel like I am close but cannot seem to see what I am doing wrong. The code for both iframe pages is below.

```
--iframeA (ifr1.htm)
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var var_name = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    </script>
<body>
<input type="text" name"textbox" id="textbox"/>
</body>
</html>


--iframeB (ifr2.htm)
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function f2(txt){
    var name2 = parent.ifr1.var_name;
    document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = name2;
    }
    </script>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <button onclick="f2('complete')"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could be a race condition. at the time the frameB code runs, frame A might not have completed loading, so `var_name` isn't defined yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> parent.ifr1.var_name;
> ```

I would recommend `parent.frames.ifr1.var_name`

> it just displays undefined:
>
> ```
> var var_name = document.getElementById("textbox").value;</script>
> </script>
> …
> <input type="text" name"textbox" id="textbox"/>
> ```

You're assigning the value of the input only once, when the document is loading (I doubt that it [works at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572) actually). When you later type anything in, the value of `var_name` never changes.

Instead, you want to get the value when the button is clicked:

```
function f2(txt){
    var name2 = parent.frames.ifr1.document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = name2;
}
```

(and you can remove the script from `ifr1.htm`). Alternatively, use this for the first iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name"textbox" id="textbox"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var var_name;
    document.getElementById("textbox").onchange = function(e) {
         var_name = this.value;
    };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked! What if i wanted to have the frame display a input from a text box on the main page, and eliminate iframeA, is that difficult to do?

Comment: No. You would simply access `parent` instead of `parent.frames.ifrm1`; and what I said about the input now holds equally for the parent window.